# Is there a limit to the query length being passed to ADODB?

Tags: sql, vba, excel, adodb

I am currently testing a framework that stores a SQL query in a cell on an excel workbook and then passes the cell value to a variable. This variable then gets executed through `rs.Open query, cn` where:

```vb
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset 
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
```

and I have tried these for "query" :

```vb
Dim query as String
Dim query as Variant
```

or even playing with fixed length queries:

```vb
Dim query as String * 9999
```

In playing with the output of the query string, it cuts off somewhere around 8000. Google is coming up short for me, so I am coming here for answers. Is there a specific limit to what a variable can pass to `recordset.Open()`?

NB: The connection string I am using for this particular query is :
    ConnectionString = "User ID=User;Password=PW;Data Source=DB;Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle"

But if you know whether there is a system specific limit for Oracle, NetezzaSQL, or MS SQL Server (SQLOLEDB.1) please let me know. I will need to specify the limitations of each in order to define which new queries will need to be converted into stored procedures.

Here is the essentials of the code:

```vb
Sub RunQueryTable()

Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim RS As ADODB.Recordset
Dim iCols As Integer
Dim DB As String, User As String, PW As String
Dim SQLTable As Worksheet
Dim ConnectionString as String
Dim query As String 'Or Dim query As Variant 'Or Dim query As String * 9999
Dim i As Long
etc, etc.

Set SQLTable = Sheet32
Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
Set RS = New ADODB.Recordset

DB = _____
User = ______
PW = ____

ConnectionString = "User ID=" & User & _
                   ";Password=" & PW & _
                   ";Data Source=" & DB & _
                   ";Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle"

query = SQLTable.Cells(i, 3).Text

cn.Open (ConnectionString)
RS.CursorType = adOpenForwardOnly
RS.Open (query), cn

For iCols = 0 To RS.Fields.count - 1
    Worksheets("Output").Cells(1, iCols + 1).Value = RS.Fields(iCols).Name
Next
Worksheets("Output").Cells(2, "A").CopyFromRecordset RS

RS.Close
cn.Close

End Sub
```

The specific error I am getting from VBA is : "ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected" because the query is getting cut off.

Comment: Please add your actual code and the database you're using.

Comment: Why the hell would you have a 8K+ character inline SQL query in your VBA code??!! Ever heard of stored procedures? They do wonders!

Comment: That said 8K characters makes sense, that's `nvarchar(max)` (assuming SQL Server - please [edit] your question to clarify). Probably driven by the server, not ADODB.

Comment: The query runs fine in Toad, which is part of my confusion here.

Comment: @Mat'sMug - `...where myField in ([long list of values sourced from worksheet])...` is something I do pretty often.  Theoretically you could insert all those values into a table and perform a join, but sometimes the basic approach works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's your problem:

```
query = SQLTable.Cells(i, 3).Text
```

Consider:

```
Range("A1").Value=string(12000,"*")
? len(range("a1").value) '>> 12000
? len(range("a1").text) '>> 8221
```

Comment: Nice one! I still don't think having anything but trivial queries is a good maintainable solution. Editing 8000+ character queries is done in SSMS (or whatever you use to edit SQL with your favorite RDBMS), not an Excel cell; can't shake the feeling that they should be stored procedures.

Comment: Agreed - all my large queries are typically so due to use of "in" lists.

Comment: @TimWilliams Could you please let me know if I am understanding your answer correctly:   Essentially you are setting a cell's length to a fixed length of 12,000 characters. After I do that, will I be able to pass a longer string length to a variable that I can use to open a record set?

Comment: No I'm saying that if you use `.Text` to read your long SQL query from the cell it's stored in, you may not get the full SQL if it's longer than 8221 characters.  You should use `.Value` instead.  Those three lines of code I posted are just to illustrate the problem with using `.Text`